# MySQL 5.6 ExtractValue XPath concat

Tags: mysql, xml, xpath, mysql-5.6

I don't understand why extractvalue doesn't returns values of attributes when use MySQL concat function.

```
SET @xml = '<items>
<docHeader companyIdIssuer="company" docTypeId="2" companyIdReceiver="nin" dateIssue="2018-12-28">
    <attribute attributeId="2" value="1236"/>
    <docDetail productId="1" valor="some value">
        <variable variableId="6" value="12.3" unitId="34"/>
        <variable variableId="7" value="2.3" unitId="34"/>
        <variable variableId="3" value="4.325" unitId="34"/>
        <variable variableId="5" value="20" unitId="106"/>
        <attribute attributeId="1" value="1236"/>
    </docDetail>
</docHeader>
</items>';

SET @headerAttributePath = '//items/docHeader[1]/attribute[1]';
SET @detailPath = '//items/docHeader[1]/docDetail[1]';
SET @detailAttributePath = '//items/docHeader[1]/docDetail[1]/attribute[1]';

select  extractValue(@xml, concat(@headerAttributePath, '/@attributeId')) AS attIdConcat,
        extractValue(@xml, '//items/docHeader[1]/attribute[1]/@attributeId') AS attIdPlain,
        extractValue(@xml, concat(@headerAttributePath, '/@value')) AS attValueConcat,
        extractValue(@xml, '//items/docHeader[1]/attribute[1]/@value') AS attValuePlain,
        @headerAttributePath AS attHeaderPath,
        concat(@headerAttributePath, '/@value') AS attValuePathConcat,
        '//items/docHeader[1]/attribute[1]/@value' AS attValuePathPlain,
        STRCMP(concat(@headerAttributePath, '/@value'), '//items/docHeader[1]/attribute[1]/@value') AS pathStrComp,
        extractValue(@xml, concat(@detailPath, '/@valor')) AS detValueConcat,
        extractValue(@xml, concat(@detailAttributePath, '/@attributeId')) AS attDetIdConcat,
        extractValue(@xml, concat(@detailAttributePath, '/@value')) AS attDetValueConcat;
```

Sample: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/74620/4)

Comment: It works in MySQL 8.0. Looks like a bug in 5.x that was fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A rather peculiar case, it seems that the combination of some paths, for example, `items -> docHeader -> attribute -> @value` or `items -> docHeader -> docDetail -> @valor`, produces errors in the parsing, which is a bug.

Some workarounds:

- If you can not change the name of any of the elements, you can use the [CAST()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) function in CONCAT function.
- Rename one of the elements, for example, `docHeader` to `doc_Header`, `attribute` to `attr` or `valor` to `_valor`.

See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eMsBBQVikV3szVdXEFX79Q/0).

As mentioned @Barmar, in MySQL 8.0, everything works as expected, see [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eowZhPjtvAsdP17pDTtgpm/0).

**UPDATE**

After some additional testing, we can see the problem also occurs when the total length of the path does not achieve a certain character length, see [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/35ziJmMqEd9Ebd1WpHeL55/0).

Comment: Thanks. I solved the problem using a short tag name "attr" plus CAST(… CHAR). I don't know if this definitely solves the problem, because XML have variable length. But, it's a good approach.

Comment: @René: In all my tests, the most reliable alternative was `CAST(... AS CHAR)` regardless of the length of the XML.